# php replace regular expression

Tags: php, regex, replace

I need to use php to add a space between a period and the next word/letter when there's none.

For example, "This is a sentence.This is the next one." needs to become "This is a sentence. This is the next one." Notice the added space after the first period.

My problem is that even if I'm able to make a regular expression that finds every dot followed by a letter, how do I then replace that dot with a "dot + space" and keep the letter?

Also it needs to keep the case of the letter, lower or upper.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Doing this via regex will lead to false results with things like `This is a sentence."And is a quote." And this contains three dots...` and all other kinds of situation where a dot is valid but a following space is wrong. You can't, in fact, parse natural language correctly with regular expressions, and even more sophisticated tools have a *very* hard time with that.

Comment: While this is true, it will at least allow me to correct some of the most obvious mistakes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$regex = '#\.(\w)#';
$string = preg_replace($regex, '. \1', $string);
```

If you want to capture more than just periods, you can do:

```
preg_replace('#(\.|,|\?|!)(\w)#', '\1 \2', $string);
```

Simply add the characters you want replaced into the first () block.  Don't forget to escape special characters (http://us.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php)

Comment: Thank you very much! So basically the \1 is the variable containing the letter. Do you mind explaining this or pointing me somewhere I can better understand it?

Comment: \1 is what is captured in the first group (regex contained within the first group of parentheses). It's called a back reference.

Comment: That fails if you have something else than a word character after the dot, like the string "Foo.-Bar"

Comment: What if I want to do this for periods or commas. Now I need two back references right? How would that work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "Will you please slow down?You're gonna kill someone.Seriously!";
echo preg_replace('/(!|\?|\.)([^\s\.\?!])/', '\1 \2', $str);
```

Comment: FYI, `(!|\?|\.)` can be written as `[!?.]`, making it more efficient as well as more readable.

Comment: @Alan, you'd need to wrap the [] in () as well for the backreference to work ([!?.])...

Comment: @Alan Moore: True. But I wanted to see if ircmaxell would copy it verbatim (as you can see, I do use brackets in the second, albeit with superfluous espaces). lol jk

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "This is a sentence.This is the next one.";
echo preg_replace("#\.(\S)#", '. \1', $str);
```

Comment: That will erroneously turn "this..." into "this. .."

Comment: @ircmaxell, it's just what the OP asked; add a period if the following character isn't a space (I used a non-whitespace, tho). There are probably a lot of other situations where it won't work either, URIs for example.